# Let us deal with bountied questions in the LQP queue!

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts, bounty

> Spoiler alert: The review task in question is not an audit.

Ooh, bounty question!

[image: review task]

But it's not closeable!

[image: comment]

Link to review task: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5913369

Comment: Better yet, let us close it despite the bounty

Comment: @JanDvorak: Bad idea. But allowing to vote and notifying a moderator for arbitration if closing/deletion was the community-decision, for final implementation or rejection, that would be a good idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: The difference to my question (this one) to your linked one is that  mine requests to have them be deal-able (changing `Close` to `Recommend Closure` or `Recommend Community User Intervention Right Now`) directly.